# Populating JavaFX TableView with Enum data

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, tableview

I'm working on an Javafx Application for a game.
I got some Data stored in an enum but can't seem to figure out how to easily add the data to JavaFX TableView, can someone help me out.
I'll be using fxml to style the TableView.

I would like every enum vallue in an seperate row, in the columns i would like to have:

1. Icon as an Image.
2. Rank as an Integer.
3. Level as an Integer.
4. Experience as an Integer.

The Enum:

```
package org.fryslan.ec.hiscore;

import org.fryslan.ec.Core;

public enum Hiscore {

OVERALL(0, "Overall", null),
ATTACK(1, "Attack", "skill_icon_attack.gif"),
DEFENCE(2, "Defence", "skill_icon_defence.gif"),
STRENGTH(3, "Strength", "skill_icon_strength.gif"),
HITPOINTS(4, "Hitpoints", "skill_icon_hitpoints.gif"),
RANGED(5, "Ranged", "skill_icon_ranged.gif"),
PRAYER(6, "Prayer", "skill_icon_prayer.gif"),
MAGIC(7, "Magic", "skill_icon_magic.gif"),
COOKING(8, "Cooking", "skill_icon_cooking.gif"),
WOODCUTTING(9, "Woodcutting", "skill_icon_woodcutting.gif"),
FLETCHING(10, "Fletching", "skill_icon_fletching.gif"),
FISHING(11, "Fishing", "skill_icon_fishing.gif"),
FIREMAKING(12, "Firemaking", "skill_icon_firemaking.gif"),
CRAFTING(13, "Crafting", "skill_icon_crafting.gif"),
SMITHING(14, "Smithing", "skill_icon_smithing.gif"),
MINING(15, "Mining", "skill_icon_mining.gif"),
HERBLORE(16, "Herblore", "skill_icon_herblore.gif"),
AGILITY(17, "Agility", "skill_icon_agility.gif"),
THIEVING(18, "Thieving", "skill_icon_thieving.gif"),
SLAYER(19, "Slayer", "skill_icon_slayer.gif"),
FARMING(20, "Farming", "skill_icon_farming.gif"),
RUNECRAFTING(21, "Runecrafting", "skill_icon_runecraft.gif"),
HUNTER(22, "Hunter", "skill_icon_hunter.gif"),
CONSTRUCTION(23, "Construction", "skill_icon_construction.gif");

private int id;
private String name;
private String icon;
private final String ICON_LOCATION = Core.class.getResource("\\resources\\hiscore\\").getPath();
public static String hiscoreData;

Hiscore(int id, String name, String icon) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getRank() {
    String data = hiscoreData.split(" ")[id];
    return Integer.parseInt(data.split(",")[0]);
}

public int getLevel() {
    String data = hiscoreData.split(" ")[id];
    return Integer.parseInt(data.split(",")[1]);
}

public int getExperience() {
    String data = hiscoreData.split(" ")[id];
    return Integer.parseInt(data.split(",")[2]);
}

public String getIcon() {
    return ICON_LOCATION + icon;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to display in the table, i.e. do you want one row for each enum value, and what goes in each column?

Comment: First Column the Icon as an Image.
Second Column Rank as an integer.
Third Column Level as an Integer.
Fourth Column Experience as an Integer.
and each Enum Vallue in a seperate row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no difference because you are using an `enum`: this just works exactly the same way as it would for any other class. I.e your FXML looks like

```xml
<TableView fx:id="table">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="iconCol" text="Icon"/>
    <TableColumn fx:id="rankCol" text="Rank"/>
    <TableColumn fx:id="levelCol" text="Level"/>
    <TableColumn fx:id="experience" text="Experience"/>
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

Then in your controller you do

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Hiscore> table ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Hiscore, String> iconCol ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Hiscore, Number> rankCol ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Hiscore, Number> levelCol ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Hiscore, Number> experienceCol ;

    public void initialize() {
        iconCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getIcon()));
        rankCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getRank()));
        // etc etc
    }
}
```

To display the icon as an image, you need a cell factory on the `iconCol`:

```
iconCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Hiscore, String>() {
    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    @Override 
    protected void updateItem(String imageURL, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(image, empty) ;
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            Image image = new Image(imageURL, true);
            imageView.setImage(image);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    }
});
```

This of course assumes that the `getIcon()` method is returning the appropriate URL for the image. (`ICON_LOCATION` makes no sense to me: why do you have backslashes in a URL?)

Finally, you can populate the table with

```
table.getItems().addAll(Hiscore.values());
```